# How to apply this code to all cells of dataframe in R

Tags: r

This line of code applies to a `f_name` column on my data frame and removes all the cells of `f_name` column but I want to apply it to all columns.
How do I do it?

```
subset(m, nchar(as.character(f_name)) <=  100
```

Comment: 1) You are missing a close parenthesis in the end. 2) That code line subsets the data.frame `m` given the condition that follows, i.e., a certain number of characters of column `f_name`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(m)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(m, 20))`.

Comment: I have around 20 columns and most of them contains cell with length more than 100,I want to keep only those rows whose each cell have length less than 100 in each column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data.frame is named `dat`, try the following.
It first creates a logical index `inx` with values `TRUE` if all elements of a column have less than 100 characters. It then subsets the original data.frame keeping only those columns.

```
inx <- sapply(dat, function(x) all(nchar(x) < 100))
new_dat <- dat[which(inx)]
```

Comment: Thanks Rui barradas, Thank you for the help, I want to learn r to master over it can u please tell me some online resource from where I can start from basic to all analysis and graphs etc

Comment: You should start with *An Introduction to R*, file R-intro.pdf that comes with your installation of R. Then check out the documentation that can be found on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/).